# SQL Server database - get last record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How do I we get last row in SQL Server if we don't have primary id and numeric column? For example we only have a name and a few other columns in the table

Comment: define "last row".

Comment: Well whats make a row the last row? - The order they are in if you `select *` is irrelevant and should always be considered random without an order clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the highest name, alphabetically,

```
select max(columnName) from tableName
```

If you mean the last row added to the table, it's not possible unless you have a column with the date/time inserted, or some other value like an identity column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you have a column for insertedDate you could do something like this:

```
select top (1) * from tableName order by insertedDate DESC
```

If not, for future use if you don't want an ID column, maybe you can add a default constraint for inserted date to pick from the system date, so you wouldn't have to add anything when you insert.

Answer (score 0):

With no definition of 'last row'... :

```
select top 1 *
from t
order by Name desc
```